# Android 28.0.0 v7 RecyclerView scroll issues

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

Can't seem to get a hang of what's going on in there.

Recently updated RecyclerView from a previous API-23 to API-28 and corresponding support-v7 libraries.

As dynamic content is added in the form of Views to the RecyclerView toward the bottom, the RecyclerView is scrolling automatically to the top.

My app's main-page, the one after the splash-page has 4 tabs - fragments hosted in a typical ViewPager with Tab-bar setup and everything. Each Fragment hosts a RecyclerView, backed by a typical RecyclerView.Adapter.

Here's the tricky part, there are at least 4 to 6 "different" view-types that are injected by these Adapters to the RecyclerView. Featured content, Google Ad, some form of Latest Content, Sponsored Content from a Third-party sponsor, Video-On-Demand content, Banner content etc etc.

At the very least, Featured content, Google Ad and Sponsored Content are a must, followed by any Latest Content, that may or may not also include Video-On-Demand Content. Each content-type is an independent RESTful API end-point, response-callbacks are published-and-subscribed via Otto-EventBus framework, and Adapter is populated as and how responses are received.

There lies the problem. Featured Content response may or may not be the first-response updated to the Adapter. Google Ad may or may not be the first or the last response updated to the Adapter. So also with Sponsored content. Irrespective of the order in which responses are populated to the Adapter for display, previous API-23 just worked fine with a notifyDataSetChanged().

Current API-28 auto-scrolls the RecyclerView to the top, even after using DiffUtil for every RESTful-API Response updated to the Adapter. I have exhausted all my options and solutions to prevent RecyclerView from auto-adjusting by scrolling to the top.

Any pointers to prevent RecyclerView from scrolling to the top to auto-adjust for child-views added at the bottom will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this, instead of notifying the whole dataset has changed.

```
notifyItemChanged(position);
```

Comment: Nope, didn't work. I'd expect the DiffUtil to be handling this internally anyhow, in my most latest attempt to solve the problem. The issue is that the RecyclerView adjusts by auto-scrolling to the top as new elements and views are continued to be populated toward the bottom.